# Not a single command is working with rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Whatever command like rake,rails etc I issue,I get the same error in my rails app.

```
Block not supplied (ArgumentError)

C:\Sites\merevik\merevik>rails console
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/ra
iltie/configurable.rb:24:in `class_eval': block not supplied (ArgumentError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:24:in `configure'
        from C:/Sites/merevik/merevik/config/initializers/setup_mail.rb:2:in `bl
ock in <top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:24:in `class_eval'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:24:in `configure'
        from C:/Sites/merevik/merevik/config/initializers/setup_mail.rb:1:in `<t
op (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
/lib/rails/engine.rb:588:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `block in <class:Engine>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from C:/Sites/merevik/merevik/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required
)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Provide more details. At least full stack trace

Comment: @ Alex Kliuchnikau I have added stack trace.

Comment: Do version of Rails other than 3.2.1 work? `gem install rails -v 3.2.0` for instance.

Comment: No,3.2.1 also not working.I have tested with both 3.1 and 3.2.1

Comment: Looks like there's a problem in config/initializers/setup_mail.rb. Can you temporarily remove that initializer and try it? Can you include its source above?

Comment: possible duplicate of [rails app is crashing keeps crashing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132470/rails-app-is-crashing-keeps-crashing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are calling `configure` from line 2 of `setup_mail.rb` without passing a block. On line 1, you are also calling `configure`, and passing the block which contains the faulty call on line 2. I am guessing you are doing something like:

```
configure.some_option = 'value'
```

where you really meant:

```
config.some_option = 'value'
```

This is the source for `configure`:

```
def configure(&block)
  class_eval(&block)
end
```

Calling `class_eval` without a block will always throw an `ArgumentError`.

Comment: Hope this was helpful! If it solved your problem, an upvote would be appreciated.